# Forward events / notifications to other phone

Tags: iphone, notifications

I would like to forward my iPhone notifications or alerts to an Android phone.

Is there a way/app to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think an App called "pushbullet" can probably do what you want.

Pushbullet by Pushbullet
https://appsto.re/us/02ptW.i

Quick video of setup and demonstration: https://youtu.be/BVpUbJFLRvs

Comment: I looked at that indeed, but I think it's just a generic platform for push messaging, am I wrong? If not, could you explain how to set it up or find a manual to do so?

Comment: My understanding is it forwards push notifications between devices.  I would reference this quick video on how to set it up: https://youtu.be/BVpUbJFLRvs

Comment: Upon further review - looks like iOS to Mac requires Bluetooth.  So this probably isn't what you're looking for.